# Blender 3.1 Optix Error on Manjaro - kernel_optix.ptx

Tags: cycles-render-engine, error

Since the last Manjaro Update I get an error message when I try to switch to rendered view in Blender 3.1.2 :
Failed to load Optix Kernel from: '/usr/share/blender/3.1/scripts/addons/cycles/lib/kernel_optix.ptx' (OPTIX_ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION_USE)

I tested it with Blender installed from the Manjaro Repository as well with Blender from Blender.org (extracted to a location).

Both of them gives the same error message (with different kernel_optix.ptx location of course.)
Before the update, both version worked fine.

Strangely, 3.0 (from Blender.org) works without a Problem.
Does anyone else experiencing the same Problem?

Comment: Submit a bug report via Help > Report a Bug in Blender.

Comment: It was working (same Blender installation) before the Manjaro update so it might not be a bug in Blender itself. Before I submit a bug report, I would like to know if it's just me who has this problem or other Manjaro users as well. (In the Manjaro Forum are far less Blender users as here, therefore I ask it here.)

Comment: Fair enough, but since you haven't had any other comments here I'd still suggest submitting a report so that the Blender developers can test it with the latest Manjaro version to see what's going on.

Comment: You are right. As it seems it only affects me. I submitted a bug report. Lets see what the outcome will be.

Answer (score 0):

There was a second user who had the same Problem (with Ubuntu instead of Manjaro) and commented on my bug report. After he started with clean 3.1 settings, the problem disappeared. **I can confirm that creating new settings instead of copying the 3.0 settings solves the problem.**

I experimented a bit with my 3.0 settings in 3.1 afterwards. The settings themselves without add-ons worked. Then I started to disable the Add-ons and as soon as Sverchok was disabled, the problem disappeared again. Strangely, after re-enabling Sverchok the problem didn't came back so I don't understand why this problem happened. (My question if the other user also uses Sverchok was not answered.) It seems to be a very rare Problem and the solution at the end is simple.

Comment: maybe to completely remove sverchok (when updating from button there mey be left some old files). and try again

Comment: In the meantime I figured out that it wasn't Sverchok. It is the LuxCore renderer. If I deactivate LuxCore in the Add-Ons, everything is fine. If I activate it, Optix for Cycles is broken. I haven't continued to write here or in the Blender bug report because apparently I'm the only one left who has this problem.